# Invoking a method by its name

Tags: java, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

I have 10 methods named: `m1`, `m2`, `m3`,...

like this:

```
public void m1(){
..
}
```

How do I invoke them with string in a 'for' loop?

I want to do this:

```
for (int i=1;i<11;i++){
   invoke('m'+i);
}
```

Comment: You need to use a feature called "Reflection"

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate.  The simple answer is use reflection but a design like this is wrong.  You should, until Java gets first-class methods in the form of closures being using an interface to define the method signature and iterating over objects that implement that interface calling the method it defines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `reflection` to achieve this.

```
    Method method = getClass().getMethod(methodName);
    method.invoke(this);
```

So, you need to store your method names in an array and use this code piece to call those methods one by one.

Comment: ill just add and say that if u wish to add a parameter, add his Class in the getmethod() as 2nd parameter, and add the parameter in the invoke() as the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

However, I would be interested in your use case. Often it is possible to refactor an application, so that the use of reflection is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

Use java reflection on `this` object.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Was it not the purpose to offer some guidelines, hints and not specific answers? I mean, teach a man how to fish, but not give him the already caught fish...

Comment: your answer seems to be comment and not a real answer. If you want to give good answer write good description and proper formated answer..