# How to invoke a method with the methods name as a string

Tags: python, getattr

I am using Biopython's Restriction class to perform in silico restriction digestions. As I understand it, in order to digest a certain sequence with a certain enzyme, the .catalyze() method must be implemented.

```
digestTuple = Restriction.EcoRI.catalyse(this_seq)  # Or whichever enzyme is desired.
```

Right now I apply a conditional to see which enzyme is being used as input. For Example:

```
RS = restrictionSite         # From user
amb = IUPACAmbiguousDNA()
this_seq = Seq(sequence, amb) # sequence from user

if RS == 'EcoRI':
    digestTuple = Restriction.EcoRI.catalyse(this_seq)
```

I apply a conditional for any enzymes that I would foresee myself needing. This takes up a bunch of lines of code and is inefficient. I would like to be able to search for membership in Restrictions set of all possible enzymes, Restriction.AllEnzymes. Something like this:

```
if RS in Restriction.AllEnzymes:
    digestTuble = Restriction.RS.catalyze(this_seq)

else:
    print('Please type in enzyme name correctly')
```

This problem is that python doesn't equate:

```
RS = "EcoRI" 
digestTuple = Restriction.RS.catalyze(this_seq)
```

with

```
digestTuple = Restriction.EcoRI.catalyze(this_seq)
```

As it is trying to use the string name associated with the enzyme and not actually invoking the proper method.

Is there a way to invoke this method using the single conditional that searches all possible enzymes?

Maybe something like this [Invoking a method by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496670/invoking-a-method-by-its-name) but in python?

The technical wording regarding this question is a little confusing for me, so I probably did not explain the problem accurately. Ill happily answer any clarifying questions.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734618/dynamic-method-call-in-python-2-7-using-strings-of-method-names/17734692#17734692 perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getattr()`, e.g.:

```
RS = "EcoRI"
digestTuple = getattr(Restriction, RS).catalyze(this_seq)
```

Comment: Both answers and the comment worked perfectly thank you! I gave you the nod because I think you beat the second comment by a hair. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As simple as:

```
getattr(your_object,"methodname")()
```

example:

```
class My_Class:
    def print_hi(self):
        print 'hi'

a = My_Class()

getattr(a,'print_hi')()
```

output:

```
hi
```

In your case:

```
RS = "EcoRI" 
digestTuple = getattr(Restriction, RS).catalyze(this_seq)
```